# CloudWatch Custom Dashboard - Period Setting

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-cloudwatch, amazon-cloudwatchlogs

[image: CloudWatch Dashboard]

I'm trying to set up a custom dashboard in CloudWatch, and don't understand how "Period" is affecting how my data is being displayed.

Couldn't find any coverage of this variable in the AWS documentation, so any guidance would be appreciated!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Period is the width of the time range of each datapoint on a graph and it's used to define the granularity at which you want to view your data.

For example, if you're graphing total number of visits to your site during a day you could set the period to 1h, which would plot 24 datapoints and you will see how many visitors you had in each hour of that day. If you set the period to 1min, graph will display 1440 datapoints and you will see how many visitors you had each in minute of that day.

See the CloudWatch docs for more details:
http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonCloudWatch/latest/monitoring/cloudwatch_concepts.html#CloudWatchPeriods

Here is a similar question that might be useful:
[API Gateway Cloudwatch advanced logging](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45429429/api-gateway-cloudwatch-advanced-logging)

Comment: Thank you! That was just the documentation I was trying to find.